# One Slider results the summation of another two Sliders using Bootstrap Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to update the value of Slider1 with the summation of Slider2 and Slider3, but it is only showing the value of either Slider1 or Slider2, whichever is moving. I am making some mistake in updating the value tp the Slider1.

[Here is the Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hawkeye15/qng5935v/11/)

**code.html**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <p>
    Slider1
    </p>
    <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="50" data-slider-step="1" />
        <hr />
        <p>
    Slider2
    </p>
        <input id="ex2" data-slider-id='ex2Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" />
        <hr />
        <p>
    Slider3
    </p>
        <input id="ex3" data-slider-id='ex3Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" />
        <hr />

    </div>
```

**Javscript.js**

```
    var minSliderValue1 = $("#ex1").data("slider-min");
    var maxSliderValue1 = $("#ex1").data("slider-max");
    var minSliderValue2 = $("#ex2").data("slider-min");
    var maxSliderValue2 = $("#ex2").data("slider-max");

    $('#ex1').slider({
        value : 0,
      formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
      }
    });

    $('#ex2').slider({
        value : 0,
      formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
      }
    });

    $('#ex3').slider({
        value : 0,
    });

    // If You want to change input text using slider handler
    $('#ex1').on('slide', function(slider){
      $("#ex3,#ex2").val(slider.value);
    });

    // If you want to change slider using input text
    $("#ex3,#ex2").on("slide", function() {
        var val = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value, 10) || (minSliderValue1+minSliderValue2));
        this.value = val > (maxSliderValue1+maxSliderValue2) ? (maxSliderValue1+maxSliderValue2) : val;
        $('#ex1').slider('setValue', val);
    });
```

**code.css**

```
    .wrapper {
        padding : 20px;
        margin-top : 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is coming from `$('#ex1').slider('setValue', val);`. `val` is only going to contain the value of the slider currently being slid, not the sum of both of them.

Also, perhaps you want to be setting the `min` and `max` values for sliders 2 and 3, rather than 1 and 2 (if you're using 1 as the sum of the 2 and 3).

**UPDATE TO INCLUDE CODE ADJUSTMENTS**

All you need in the `slide` event listener is:

```
$('#ex1').slider('setValue', $('#ex2').slider('getValue') + $('#ex3').slider('getValue'));
```

So the updated function would be:

```
// If you want to change slider using input text
$("#ex3,#ex2").on("slide", function() {
    $('#ex1').slider('setValue', $('#ex2').slider('getValue') + $('#ex3').slider('getValue'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qng5935v/12/

Comment: then how to update it to the sum, I am not able to figure out how to do that. You are right about the problem. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment